# Как найти совпадения телефона по базе с телефоном из телефонии БД?

Tags: php, mysql

От телефонии приходит номер телефона в API системы, в этот момент нужно выполнить поиск по номеру телефона...

Мой код:

```
//$phone_client - переменная содержит номер телефона.

$result_client = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `lids` WHERE id_cabinet = '$id_cabinet'"); // ограничиваем поиск до нужного кабинета
$myrow_client = mysql_fetch_array($result_client);

if ($myrow_client['tel'] == $phone_client) {
  //если совпадение найдено, то добавляем id клиента в поле по id звонка
}
```

**Как сделать поиск более правильным и с минимальным количеством ошибок чтобы был?**

Comment: Видимо не надо читать всю таблицу а явно задать условие с номером телефона в самом sql запросе

Comment: И не класть значения переменных в сам запрос, а использовать привязываемые параметры. см. mysqli_bind_param()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно выбрать единый стиль для хранения номеров, что бы далее можно было привести к тому же виду полученный номер и искать в базе.

К примеру можно хотя бы убрать все что не цыфры:

```
$phone_number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phone_number);
//save phone
```

При поиске так же из строки удалить все что не цифры и искать в базе:

```
$phone_client = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phone_client);

//Выбираем только одну запись
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `lids` WHERE id_cabinet = :room AND tel = :phone LIMIT 1";
$pdo->prepare($sql);
$pdo->execute([':room'=>$id_cabinet, ':phone'=>$phone_client]);
if(($result = $pdo->fetch()){
    print_r($result);
};
```

*mysql - Это расширение устарело с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удално с выпуска 7.0.0. 
Используйте [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php)*

Принцип как хранение паролей пользователей, при сохранении кодируете, при поиске кодируете пришедший пароль и сравниваете с тем что в базе.

Если у вас могут приходить разные форматы, к примеру сохранили вы с кодом страны, а может прийти номер без кода, можно искать просто по вхождению строки ([sql_like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)).

Можете попробовать использовать библиотеку [libphonenumber](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php), с ее помощью можно получить информацию о номере, проверить на валидность, выбрать какой то из форматов.

Comment: спасибо, знаю про mysql боюсь переходить просто на последнюю... чую все коды сайтов придется перелопачивать...

Comment: парой нет смысла переводить старые и большие проекты на новое, но ответ могут находить люди позднее, и многие принимают код на веру, в итоге сейчас многие используют mysql просто потому что находят их в старых ответах, гайдах и т.п.

Comment: вот у меня проект crm системы, боюсь переводить ее на новый php просто потому-что люди там работают почти постоянно... но знаю что рано или поздно нужно будет сделать это, так как иначе развивать ее возможности просто не будет возможным...

Comment: Ну если планируется развитие системы, то конечно стоит этим вопросом заняться. Тем более никто не заставляет делать все и сразу, добавьте конфиг для базы через иное расширение, и частями заменяйте, выйдет проект где будет часть на старом часть на новом, главное одну часть постепенно уменьшать другую увеличивать и постепенно перейдете к новому.

Comment: в принципе так и подумывал. Вот уже пора сокет вводить для вызова карточки клиента